# Reviewer based code repository management with git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository, cvs

fairly new to git here. I would like to ask what you think is the best way to implement the following source code management process with git (or other SCM systems):

> - Before committing code for certain parts of the system (i.e.  system framework), changes must be reviewed first by the assigned reviewer. The reviewer is then notified afterwards. ***Or preferably:*** a set of reviewers do not need to be notified, they should have a way to view pending changes on the whole system which they can assign to each of themselves for review.
> - The reviewer then pulls the code changes from some location and reviews it.
> - If the reviewer finds the code acceptable he commits it himself to the central repository, else simply removes the file from the list of files for review. The developer who has set the change for review is notified afterwards.

What we have thought of so far:

- Use git. Changes of developers must be committed to their local repository for review.
- The reviewer pulls the changes from the remote repository of the developer above.
- The reviewer then decides the fate of the change, whether to commit or scrap it.

We thought the above approach is too tedious to the review. For one, he needs to save the repository of each developer that will be reviewed and secondly, he needs to find the file for review in the whole remote repository.

So we then changed it to something like this:

- Still use git. Changes for review of developers must be committed to the remote repository of the reviewer. This repository should only contain files for review.
- The reviewer then compares his current copy of the file and the newest one which was committed by the developer above.
- The reviewer then decides the fate of the change, whether to commit or scrap it.

Still, this does not eliminate the effort to manually commit the reviewed changes to the central repository. Any better suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like [GitHub's pull request model](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).  It's common and works really well, but requires tool support to make it not tedious as you've come to realize.